# Grails query database server

Tags: grails

Can I execute this sentence using grails? How?

```
select @@global.max_allowed_packet;
```

The why:
I want to make sure the user inserts a file not greater than the allowed.

Cons: 
As I see it, programmer will have the ability to make this query: show databases; (something that people may say it is a security leak).
Pros:
User will be warned if he tries to insert a file greater than the allowed.

To consider:
The max_allowed_packet is something the programmer doesn't know or have the ability to change 'cause of server admin.

Thanks 4 your well received comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the groovy Sql class from within a service class?

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
class DbConfigService {
   javax.sql.DataSource dataSource // For spring

   def maxPacket(){
      def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      sql.firstRow('select @@global.max_allowed_packet;').max_allowed_packet
   }
}
```